# Where in the standard does it say that the typedef below is valid?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, typedef

Both `g++` and `clang++` [compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dYOc7IT37Q1OobBq) this snippet:

```
typedef int int3[];
int3 i { 0, 1, 2 };
```

But where in the standard does it say that the array `typedef` declaration above is valid?

How do you infer that `int3[]` is a "synonym" for `int[]`?

Comment: Well, it's inherited from C; there, a typedef mimics a regular variable declaration; but because it is preceded by the typedef keyword it declares a type, not a variable. If the variable declaration is valid, so is the corresponding typedef. (This is obviously not the answer you asked for but the underlying rationale and mechanism.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I have just realized that this is the right answer ("a typedef mimics a regular variable declaration"), Great answer BTW.

Answer (score 4):

> *But where in the standard does it say that the typedef declaration above is valid?*

It's valid. As per the standard:

#### 9.2.4  The typedef specifier [dcl.typedef]

> 1 - Declarations containing the decl-specifier typedef declare identifiers that can be used later for naming fundamental (6.8.2) or compound (6.8.3) types. [...]

Where:

#### 6.8.3  Compound types [basic.compound]

> 1 - Compound types can be constructed in the following ways:
>
> — (1.1) arrays of objects of a given type, 9.3.4.5;
>
> [...]

---

> *How do you infer that `int3[]` is a "synonym" for `int[]`?*

The declaration is well defined, including for arrays with unknown bounds:

#### 9.3.4.5  Arrays [dcl.array]

> [...]
>
> 5 - Any type of the form “cv-qualifier-seq array of N U” is adjusted to “array of N cv-qualifier-seq U”, and similarly for “array of unknown bound of U”.
>
> [...]

Comment: Mudei de ideia a respeito da sua resposta. Veja o meu comtário acima para o Peter. De qualquer forma, lhe agradeço pela sua colaboração.

Comment: @Alexander you're free to accept whatever answer you see fit, you don't need to justify yourself (though I appreciate it), but I have to disagree, Peter comment is very accurate, but your question regards the standard and is tagged language lawyer, so I believe this is the answer to your question.

Comment: @Alexander, podia ter respondido em pt, desculpa, é o hábito 